# How to create a parameter in App Intent to get photos from photo library?

Tags: ios, shortcut, photo

I have tried

```swift
 @Parameter(title: "Images", supportedTypeIdentifiers: ["com.apple.live-photo"])
  var images:[IntentFile]
```

But it can only open File app and filter with the file type. I want to add "selected photos from Photo Library" on the beginning and make the results as accept parameter of the Images.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I just solved the problem. Just long press the parameter then I can choose the photos.